# Grails - Problems deploying WAR to tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I'm currently trying to deploy my freshly generated grails WAR file to a tomcat server. However, I'm getting the following error in the stacktrace.log and hence the application doesn't start.

```
2014-09-05 14:19:59,891 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-4] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT FILENAME,AUTHOR,ID,MD5SUM,DATEEXECUTED,ORDEREXECUTED,TAG,EXECTYPE FROM `DATABASECHANGELOG` ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC: Table 'aedb.databasechangelog' doesn't exist
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:142)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:150)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForList(JdbcExecutor.java:202)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForList(JdbcExecutor.java:197)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.getRanChangeSetList(AbstractDatabase.java:921)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:132)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:625)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner.runMigrations(MigrationRunner.groovy:96)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner$_autoRun_closure1.doCall(MigrationRunner.groovy:76)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner.autoRun(MigrationRunner.groovy:56)
    at DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:96)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'aedb.databasechangelog' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:128)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    ... 12 more
```

I don't have any idea about what the reason could be. Because starting the application within GGTS is possible without any problems. Maybe you have got an idea. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the [grails datasource environments](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments)?
If you deploy to a (remote) tomcat, the 'development' environment is no longer active. So there's no datasource defined for the tomcat instance, hence the complaint about the missing table.

Comment: I have defined a production dataSource as well. from my point of view that should be the one used when deploying the war.

Comment: And the aedb.databasechangelog table is present in the production db?

Comment: Well, no, but do I have to create it myself? I thought it would be created automatically - as happened in my development env

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe in the dev environment the drop-create hibernate setting was active, and on prd it's not?

Comment: no, that's deactivated generally because i use database-migration plugin

Answer (score 0):

When using Database Migration (Liquibase), make sure there is no dbCreate in your dataSource.